# Could someone help me in making my pyautogui automation run faster?

Tags: python, pyautogui

So I made a bot that tries to play this knockoff piano tiles game:http://tanksw.com/piano-tiles/
but I just can't get it to run fast enough, also I can't use win32api because I'm one a mac here's the code:

```html
import pyautogui

pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.0

# Tile 1 Position: X:  820 Y:  836
# Tile 2 Position: X:  915 Y:  836
# Tile 3 Position: X:  1010 Y:  836
# Tile 4 Position: X:  1120 Y:  836

while True:

    if pyautogui.pixel(820, 678)[0] == 17:
        pyautogui.press('a')
    elif pyautogui.pixel(915, 678)[0] == 17:
        pyautogui.press('s')
    elif pyautogui.pixel(1010, 678)[0] == 17:
        pyautogui.press('d')
    elif pyautogui.pixel(1120, 678)[0] == 17:
        pyautogui.press('f')
```

If anyone could help I would be really grateful :)

Comment: What's your target time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.pixel() is particularly slow because it takes a screenshot each time.

It's quicker to take a screenshot once, then check each position in turn; but you do need to refresh the screenshot each time you expect something to change.

e.g here's a mouse-click based version: (where `positions` is a list of tuple co-ordinates)

```
    im = pyautogui.screenshot()

    for x, y in positions:

        if im.getpixel((x, y))==(17, 17, 17):
            pyautogui.click(x, y)
            break
```

this is at least 40% faster than using pixels() to check each position

Comment: Also, you can then use this method to read-ahead and throw in some double-clicks when there are double tiles coming up etc.. I've got it down to 4.8 on a lucky run¬